# Can leaving out the "do" in a do-while loop still work?

Tags: c, do-while

I'm looking at some C code from my textbook, and it includes these lines

```
...
lastsec = get_seconds();
 sec0 = get_seconds(); while (sec0 == lastsec);
...
```

It looks rather like a `do` is missing at the end of that second line--but in any case code it should still compile.

I'm scratching my head as to how this loop wouldn't just sit at the `while (sec0 == lastsec);` until the end of time--assuming that `get_seconds()` didn't increment...

The book is Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach, Fifth Edition.
[Here's the code on page 134.](http://books.google.com/books?id=gQ-fSqbLfFoC&pg=PA134#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a printing problem of the book. Look at the page, there are 2 other loops below the one you asked for, where the `do {` is missing. They even have the closing bracket of the block but no corresponding open bracket, and that twice. Even the comments talk about a loop `/* repeat until collect 20 seconds*/`

In my opinion, the printer swallowed the `do`s (probably that the printing language has that as a keyword or something like that).

From a logical point of view, it is a `do while();` loop.

Comment: Yeah, I bet this is it! I also found another version online that includes the `do`s; this was definitely a typo!

Answer (score 6):

This is not a `do-while` loop, simply a `while` loop with empty body. In this case it seems this will either cause infinite loop or will never be executed.

Comment: Except if sec0 or lastsec are `volatile` updated outside of the control of the C program (interrupt, memory mapped hardware register).

Answer (score 3):

It's either infinite loop or condition fails the first time.

Possibly one of the variables in the condition is `volatile` and is asynchronously updated by some one else (thread, hardware etc) then it says: *wait until condition becomes false*.

Otherwise, it makes no sense to have such a loop.

Comment: +1, it's most likely a busy-wait loop rather than an infinite one.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not being updated. If you look at the linked source program (it's only a page long), you see that no variables are `volatile`; you also see `get_seconds()` is only a simple wrapper for `_time64()`.

Answer (score 1):

in C there is 2 kind of while loop:

1)

```
do {.....} while(CONDITION);
```

2)

```
while(CONDITION) {........}
```

the  `while(CONDITION) {........}` could be reduced to `while(CONDITION)` in some cases

for example if we want to copy char array we can do it in this way:

```
char *SRC="any string";
char DST[10]={0};
char *src = SRC, *dst =DST;
while(*dst++=*src++);
```

In the above example there is incrementation of `src` and `dst` pointer and the while will stop if the `*src == null character`.